# CSS and JS not showing up in my HEAD when deployed to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have just deployed a project to heroku after all of my changes were pushed to github. Everything worked fine except I noticed some new css that was updated did not go through. The css files were definitely committed and pushed to github, so I know this is not the problem.

When viewing the source on the heroku app, I notice that it is missing most of the .css and .js files in the head section. Is there a reason the head would be different on heroku than it is on my local. Everything was running smoothly and I didn't change any config files since my last push to heroku...

Thanks.

Here is a link to the github project: https://github.com/michaelnavarro/careerfoundry

application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

application.css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */

/*

 */
```

Comment: Yes, it and this reason is called Asset Pipeline. In production, all your JavaScript and CSS files should be minified and included in `application.js` and `application.css` files (by default).

Comment: @MarekLipka it seemed like this was happening automatically before? does this mean i need to add the new .css file that was added before the last commit to the application .css file? Because as far as i can tell, none of the other css files are being called directly into the applicaiton.css file

Comment: @MarekLipka as far as i know,e verything included in the assets/stylesheets tree is automatically added to application.css

Comment: Usually new css/js files are included automatically through `//= require_tree .` (`*= require_tree .` for css) directive. Please show your layout code (i.e. how you include these files in development mode).

Comment: here is a link to the github project:https://github.com/michaelnavarro/careerfoundry

Comment: @MarekLipka I've posted my application.js and application.css above.

Comment: try update production .rb with `config.assets.compile = true` and `config.serve_static_assets = true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably precompile your assets:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Then add to the files to git

```
git add .
git commit -m "compiled assests"
```

Then push to Heroku.  Heroku's asset compiler is finicky and doesn't work all the time.  You should do it locally and push everything to Heroku.

Comment: is there a solution to automatically precompile? or do i have to do it manually every time?

Comment: You have to manually compile every time.  Just run the precompile statement before you push to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the CSS files have the SCSS extension. Try renaming them to just .css.

Also, your page specific javascript files are empty, so nothing would be included from those.